# Looking for a faster way than for-loop to search and append DataFrame with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a faster alternative for this function:

```
def add_weather_data(data, weather):
    w = pd.DataFrame()
    for date in data.date:
        w = w.append(weather.iloc[weather.index.get_loc(date, method='nearest')])
    return pd.concat([data, w.set_index(data.index)], axis=1)
```

To elaborate, I have two DataFrames: `data` contains my dataset along with a column named `date` populated with `pd.Timestamp`'s, while `weather` contains data indexed with `DatetimeIndex`. For every row in `data`, I wish to search for the index nearest to `data.date` in `weather` and append that row from `weather` to this row of `data`(discarding the `DatetimeIndex` in `weather`).

Is there a better alternative to my function above? My method seems to take ages to run... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`pd.DataFrame.reindex`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `method='nearest'`

```
def add_weather_data(data, weather):
    w = weather.reindex(data.date, method='nearest')
    return pd.concat([data.set_index('date'), w], axis=1)
```

Consider the sample dataframes `data` and `weather`

```
data = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.date_range('2017-03-31', periods=5), A=range(5)))

tidx = pd.date_range('2017-03-01', '2017-04-05', freq='7H')
weather = pd.DataFrame(dict(B=range(len(tidx))), tidx)
```

Then

```
add_weather_data(data, weather)

            A    B
date              
2017-03-31  0  103
2017-04-01  1  106
2017-04-02  2  110
2017-04-03  3  113
2017-04-04  4  117
```

---

**Response to Comment**

```
def add_weather_data(data, weather):
    w = weather.reindex(data.date, method='nearest')
    return data.join(w, on='date')
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! I had to add `data = data[data.date.apply(pd.Timestamp.tzname).apply(pd.notnull)]` to the function in order to get rid of some TypeErrors that I believe due to a few rows not having timezones set (i.e., comparing tz and non-tz data lead to errors).

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that I could preserve the original `data.index` and not have to reindex that df with dates?

Answer (score 0):

how about simply [joining](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the tables?

But it looks like you are wanting the nearest date. Maybe create a table that has all dates and uses the Pandas `interpolate` function to fill in missing values. Then join that to the original dataframe?